# What is the best way of keeping track of academic readings and persons?

Tags: phd, research-process, citations, tools

I have started a brand new research from start of the year. I would like to know what are the easiest way of keeping track of the academic papers, journals and authors.

I use sites like Google Scholar, informatik.uni-trier.de for discovery of articles and following interesting conferences and people. I have used sites and tools like Mendeley and ResearchGate. I quite like the sites, but I am too reluctant to use them as for each of them I need to find everything by myself, create my own library to suit my interests.

I already got a warning by the stackexchange system saying **The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed.** but it would be great help if someone could explain some tools/software which do this?

Summarizing my questions:

1. How do you keep track of academic papers, authors effectively?
2. Are there any tools that can search/scrap the internet by some
   keywords/name and keep track of them? [I know of 
   Google alerts, what
   I seek is some kind of tool with a management interface]

Comment: related if not identical: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5585/how-does-one-keep-herself-updated-with-new-research-without-forgetting-older-res/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although you are aware of this already, I feel I need to state how satisfied I am with mostly using google scholar + a feed reader + a bibliography manager for this. Although it is not integrated, I don't currently feel any need to search for a better all in one platform.

I use google reader to subscribe to RSS feeds for online first and published articles for journals I am interested in (any reader which you can organize feeds into folders and search should be fine - I suspect many have better search capabilities that google reader). The vast majority of journals this is not much of a time suck to read all the titles and peruse abstracts I am interested in. The most prodiguous publications (e.g. [Science](http://www.sciencemag.org/rss/current.xml)/[Nature](http://www.nature.com/webfeeds/index.html)) are only borderline annoying with 60+ posts a week, but even that is not that difficult to quickly navigate through.

I have a few fairly specific google scholar alerts (as well as general google alerts), so as to not get too much in my inbox. I basically have a few key words in articles specific to my research interest, and I have alerts for specific authors. I also have alerts to people who cite my articles.

I use [CiteULike](http://www.citeulike.org/) to manage my bibliography + personal database on my local machine to export various formats (e.g. bibtex or specific citation format). This has the added benefit that [I can send articles directly from google reader to citeulike](http://wiki.citeulike.org/index.php/Organizing_your_library#Posting_from_Google_Reader), but I suspect the same set-up could be crafted for other bibliography managers (Zotero, Mendeley) and possible other feed readers.

---

Basically in a nut-shell,

1. feed reader to stay up to date with newly published articles in journals I am interested in,
2. google scholar alerts for potentially related material that isn't in those journals, and
3. a bibliography manager to store articles to read later on.

Comment: Could you maybe link the RSS URLs for Nature and Science which directly lead to the latest articles? I have trouble finding them.

Comment: Added links as requested @zenbomb, they are a certainly a bit annoying to find. If you use google reader you can search for feeds, and using Google Chrome I have an RSS feed extension in the address bar that is available for the Science website. Nature has a ton of separate feeds, that I just happened to find by seeing a link to at the bottom of the home page at http://www.nature.com/.

Comment: Google Reader has discontinued. What do you use as a replacement?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov - I use Digg reader now and I am quite happy with it.