# How to stay on top of recent literature?

Tags: reading, literature

When I started my Masters thesis one advice I got for getting good material to read was to subscribe to several journals' alerts system, so that I would get mails with eTOC (electronic Table of Contents).

This was pretty cool then, for months I could stay on top of what's been published out there and was up to date in my own little narrow area. Now almost 3 years later that list of journals have expanded a bit, and the more work I have at the lab more mails that accumulate in my mailbox. What used to be no more than 10 unread mails is now about 900. The output is more than I can handle, what more restrictive method can I implement?

I guess it is pretty clear that this way of following literature is not sustainable in the long run. So I wonder if there are other and perhaps better ways of staying on top of recently published articles?

---

Please note that I have checked the following two questions prior to asking this one. I do feel though my question differs from these two in its essence.

- [Am I reading enough of the scientific literature? Should I read for breadth or depth?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/50/am-i-reading-enough-of-the-scientific-literature-should-i-read-for-breadth-or-d)
- [How do we know if something relevant is already published?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5073/how-do-we-know-if-something-relevant-is-already-published)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way of keeping track of academic readings and persons?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6105/what-is-the-best-way-of-keeping-track-of-academic-readings-and-persons)

Comment: @DanielE.Shub for what it's worth, I read the question as being *“I have this method, but its output is more than I can handle… what more restrictive method can I implement?”*

Comment: @F'x precisely!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

During my PhD, I subscribed to the RSS feeds of the journals I would regularly read (started with 6 of them, ended up with a dozen). I would skim through titles of all new articles, and read abstracts of those whose title drew my eye. I then found out that some journals (*J. Chem. Phys.* in that particular case) offer specific RSS feeds for each of their sections, in addition to the “whole journal” feed. That helped reducing the number of journals I was skimming through.

Now, after the end of my PhD, my research interest are broader, the number of journals I like to watch is larger but my time is more limited. This system didn't work anymore, and I set up a new system, which has worked well for a few years. I use bibliographic databases (*SciFinder* and *Web of Science*; but I'm sure Google Scholar and PubMed have the same features) to create **publication and citation alerts**. Here's what I have set:

- **Citation alerts for all my own papers**: if someöne cites my work, there's a good chance I'll be interested in their paper. This one has two additional “strategic” bonuses: you get to keep an eye on your competition, and you can suggest newer work to other authors when relevant (*“hi there, I saw your recent paper citing my 2008 article on X, I thought you might be interested on a new extension of this algorithm that we published this year”*).
- **Publication alerts for major players** in the field of interest: I have 10 to 20 of those, watching all papers these people publish.
- **Citation alerts for some seminal or high-impact papers** by others in the field: a good way to see how a new idea is adopted/improved by the community. Those tend to trigger a massive number of cites, so you may want to get rid of them after some time. I have between 5 and 10 of those alerts at a given time.

The only drawback to this method: database updates tend to lag somewhat behind the RSS feeds of the journals themselves, so you get papers that are 2 to 8 weeks old.

---

In addition, use **conferences** to stay on top/catch up with the literature:

- Look at contributions made, see what's new and go check the relevant recent publications.
- Even if you're not at the conference, look at the online program and see what looks new.
- If you're attending, talk with people… you can also use that opportunity to ask some people (whom you do know well enough):

  > Have you seen that new technique by the team at MIT? it seems to work really well… I was wondering: what has caught *your* eye in the recent literature?

Answer (score 9):

I subscribed to the math arXiv, i.e. I signed up to be sent an email every day about the articles posted to the math arXiv (the email contains titles and abstracts).

When I first did this, I got very excited and subscribed to lots of areas that were interesting to me - geometric topology, general topology, algebraic topology, group theory, etc etc. and I swiftly got completely swamped and ended up reading nothing. I decided that this wasn't getting me anywhere, and I unsubscribed from everything except one subtopic (geometric topology) which was most relevant to me.

I also made it a part of my morning schedule to go through the arxiv email (usually sent around 5a) - wake up, read my morning webcomics, go through the arxiv emails, make a note of anything that sounds relevant to me to read later in the office.

In summary then:

1. Subscribing to the arxiv instead of a journal gives me a manageably small list of articles per day (as opposed to a long list of articles on a more spaced-out schedule)
2. ArXiv allowed me to focus in on a small field of research - this might not be possible for journals, since they potentially include articles in a range of subject matter.
3. Making it a part of my daily schedule (particularly for a time when I'm potentially procrastinating from making the bikeride to school) made me more likely to actually do it.
4. At least in mathematics, it might take quite a bit of time for a paper to make it to the publishing stage, and reading the arXiv lets me be more up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was not familiar with arXiv, will check it more thoroughly, but conceptually speaking I see two potential pitfalls: 1) it appears to be pretty narrow in terms of fields, 2) I don't see how it's different from getting eTOCs